# Responsive list layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to display some images in a 3 x 3 grid that must be responsive and the amount of images is not fixed.

How can I display this without having to create a new row for each 3 images? I mean, is it possible to create a list and automatically have line breaks if there is no room for more images in the same line?

The idea is to create like a image gallery, but I'll have to place texts along with the images.

[image: Sample image from the web]

Comment: so you want there to be 3 columns of images even on mobile? or just 3 columns on larger devices?

Comment: I need 3 columns on larger devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will give you a responsive 3 column grid regardless of mobile, tablet or desktop and uses the Bootstrap `.thumbnail` class. It will hold as many images as you want in the same row.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/jefyj8av/

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                            <p>text goes here...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                            <p>text goes here...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                            <p>text goes here...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                            <p>text goes here...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                            <p>text goes here...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                            <p>text goes here...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to always have 3 columns. If it's a small device it must change to 1 or 2 columns.

Comment: Changing `col-xs-4` to `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4` will give you 1 column on mobile, 2 columns on a table and 3 columns on desktop.

Comment: I updated the code example to show the new columns :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are committed to 3 columns then you can float them and use the nth-child selector to clear every 3 elements. For example if your div that contains the image and caption has class cat-cell then:

```
.cat-cell:nth-child(3n+1){ clear:left;} 
/* this add a clear to the 4th element so it wraps to a new line. */
```

It's also normal to want different numbers of elements in a row based on the media size. The following is a snippet of a bootstrap 3 .less file that accomplishes 2 across for xs; 3 across for small and 4 across for medium or larger:

```
.cat-cell{
&{
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:@grid-gutter-width;
}

@media(max-width:@screen-xs-max){
    &:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
@media(max-width:@screen-sm-max) and (min-width:@screen-sm){
    &:nth-child(3n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}        

@media(min-width:@screen-md){
    &:nth-child(4n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}        

}

.cat-cell{
.make-xs-column(6);
.make-sm-column(4);
.make-md-column(3);
}
```

Comment: This is for a Wordpress theme and I'm not using less or sass.